# Git move my work from a certain commit onwards to a seperate branch without changes from current parent

Tags: git, branch

So, I'm not sure my question even address the problem the best way.  I'll say the problem I have, and anyone who can offer a solution will be my hero.

I created a branch from the develop branch and did some work, added some commits, and pushed.  So it's like this:

```
develop ---- feature1
```

Then, I accidentally did:

```
develop---feature1----feature2
```

But what I needed to do was:

```
develop----feature1
   \
    \--feature2
```

Unfortunately, I had already pushed and submitted a pull request before I realized this.

Now feature1 has not been merged into develop.  I need to take feature2 completely off of feature1 and stick it back on to develop.

I hope this is clear.  Also, I apologize in advance because I'm sure this has been asked before, but I haven't found a question that worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git rebase -i` and drop the commits which are in feature1 branch.

For example:

Feature 1 has `A` and `B` commits and Feature 2 has `A, B, C, and D` commits. In your case, you want to drop A and B from Feature 2.

Please follow the steps below:

- `git rebase -i HEAD~X`  X - is the number of commits in the feature2 branch.
- Now, it will open the editor with the list of commits with `pick` as the first word
- To drop a commit, move to respective commit and delete the word `pick` and replace with letter `d`. `d` means delete commit. Please refer the image below
- Save and exit the editor. Git will delete the commit
- `git push -f origin feature2` - You have force push to the branch.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ended up giving up, gzipping my changed files, and deleting and recloning the repository.  I was getting overwhelmed, and rebasing wasn't getting me anywhere.  Worthy of an upvote, but I ended up going the nuclear route.  Thanks